# Is it possible to update Java7 without first uninstalling Java8?

Tags: java

On my MacBook I've got Java 6 through 8 installed and I happen to need and use them all on a daily basis. Lately it has been bothering me that every time I want to install an update to Java7 I need to first uninstall Java8.

So my question is: is it possible to update an older release of Java (1.7) without having to uninstall the newer one (1.8)?

Trying to run the update without first removing Java 1.8 notifies me that:

```
You are trying to install Java 7 Update 67,
however Java 8 Update 05 is already installed.
Visit java.com/newerversionexists for more information.
```

And the link points to a page that doesn't even exist at the moment.

Comment: It's been a while since you asked but I just wanted to check if you found any solution for this issue ? I'm in the same position and need to install the JDK7 72 update, and really don't want to uninstall JDK8 just to be able to do so.

Comment: Hi Niklas, I had completely forgottten about this question... For a while now the problem has been fixed (by Oracle or Apple, I don't know). I'm currently running OS X 10.10.1 with java 7.71 and 8.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Mac OS X 10.10 and the most recent JDK versions (7.72 and 8.25) the problem seems to have been fixed.